# using ansible variable in task conditonal

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements, jinja2

1. When I use an Ansible variable in the failed_when conditional, Ansible complains and fails by telling me that I cannot use Jinja2 expressions with failed_when.

Below snippet does not work:

```
  vars:
  var1: "var"
  tasks:
    - name: "sth"
      raw: "anothersth"
      register: status
      failed_when: var1 in status.stdout
```

2. I want to use a regex in the above example and use variable var1 within a regex. This also fails.
   I want to fail the task if var1 is repeated in the beginning and at the end of the stdout_lines. I was thinking something like this:

   failed_when: regex("^{{var1}}/.*/{{var1}}$") in status.stdout

I wonder whether there is a way to achieve what I intend to do?

===============================================================

Exact play and the description:

Let me explain what I am trying to do:

- run a command with "raw" module and register the stdout_lines.
- iterate over a list of items, where list is a fact of current ansible host
- use failed_when to search a pattern in the registered stdout and fail the task if it is not found

peers_underlay is a list defined in the host file:

`peers_underlay:
    - ip: "172.16.1.2"
    - ip: "172.16.1.6"`

This is the play:

`- hosts: leaf-2, spine-1
   gather_facts: no 
   tags: [ verify ]
   vars:
     bgp_underlay: "show ip bgp summary"

   tasks:
     - name: "underlay bgp test"
       raw: "{{ bgp_underlay }}"
       register: underlay_status
       with_items: "{{ peers_underlay }}"
       failed_when: not regex(".*/{{ item['ip'] }}/.*/Estab/.*") in underlay_status.stdout_lines`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Fail the task if var1 is repeated in the beginning and at the end."*

A: It's possible to [test strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings). For example, use *`regex`*

```yaml
    - hosts: localhost
      vars:
        my_stdout1: 'ABC dlkjfsldkfjsldkfj ABC'
        my_stdout2: 'alkdjflaksdjflakdjflaksjdflaksdjflasj'
        var1: 'ABC'
        my_regex: '^{{ var1 }}(.*){{ var1 }}$'
      tasks:
        - debug:
            msg: my_regex match my_stdout1
          when: my_stdout1 is regex(my_regex)
        - debug:
            msg: my_regex match my_stdout2
          when: my_stdout2 is regex(my_regex)
```

gives

```yaml
    "msg": "my_regex match my_stdout1"
```

The particular task sequence would be

```yaml
      vars:
        var1: "var"
        my_regex: '^{{ var1 }}(.*){{ var1 }}$'
      tasks:
        - name: "sth"
          raw: "anothersth"
          register: status
          failed_when: status.stdout is regex(my_regex)
```

Comment: Thank you. This may help with a different task sequence. However I do not think this is what I wanted. I updated and provided my play details. Would be happy if you could comment on those.

Comment: You're welcome. It helps with your problem as well. I've added your task sequence.

Comment: :) It worked when defined the pattern out of the task and used pattern as the input of the regex in the conditional. Ansible does not complain anymore about invalid jinja2 expression.